Magento 2 after upgrade
I have upgraded magento from 2.4.3-p2 to 2.4.7-p1.
I did it on local machine using docker/warden instance.
I use opensearch and admin shows that I`m connected.
I did
s:up,c:c,c:f, static:content:deploy indexer:reindex.
And it pass.
However i have for now two problems.
On product configurable page i do not see swatch options. Only error in console error no idea if this is related:
TypeError: $.effects.define is not a function
    at effect-blind.js:35:18
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650:33)
    at Module.check (require.js:866:51)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113:34)
    at require.js:132:23
    at require.js:1156:21
    at each (require.js:57:31)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1155:17)
    at Module.check (require.js:917:30)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1143:22)

On simple product i can see and add it proper.

I post in comment however if any one will looks for solutions.
I remove lib/web folder and replace it with new. There were updated scripts that magneto ended.

Are you using a custom theme? If so, try switching to the default Magento theme to see if you still have the error.
If there are no errors, check the files you have modified (.html, .phtml, .js, .xml) related to configurable products in your custom theme and compare them with the 2.4.7 version. Some changes might have happened.

i switch to luma and have same error. And them looks bad. Like some styles not loaded.

Turns out I have to also update entire lib/web folder.
